# How to convert JSON schema to mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema, jsonschema

Is there a way to take valid JSON schema like the one below and turn it into mongoose schema?

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "description": "some desc",
  "title": "Product",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "endpoints": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "poi": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "location_name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "distance": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This seems so basic and simple to me but I haven't found anything on the net.
There are bunch of examples on how to get JSON schema and there are bunch of examples how to create mongoose schema from objects like this:
`const newSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String });`

If I try to put JSON schema directly I get an error

```
node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:674
    throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at `' + path +
    ^

TypeError: Undefined type `Http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#` at `$schema`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
```

But I could not find anywhere on the net transfer from one type to another.
Anyone had this issue before?

EDIT:

This question was conceptually incorrect.
Basically what you do is validate JSON schema against the data **before** saving it to DB. You do this using `jsonschema` from npm or some other.
So data validating step is not directly linked with saving to DB step.
I thought you can apply JSON schema to MongoDB schema but that was not true. (especially when you have deeply nested objects - then it's a mess)

Comment: What do you mean transfer from one type to another is nowhere to be seen?

Comment: I mean I could not find it on the internet by googling.

Comment: And what is wrong with `const newSchema = new mongoose.Schema(YOUR_JSON_SCHEMA);` in your situation?

Comment: I get an error:
```
.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:674
    throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at `' + path +
    ^

TypeError: Undefined type `Http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#` at `$schema`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.

```

Comment: I think you should convert all nested object to `new Schema` too.

Comment: Good idea but it didn't work :)  I removed nested objects and tried with that but still getting the same error.

Comment: For every key you should provide `{type: 'SOME_MONGOOSE_TYPE'}`. So every key in your json should be object in which exists type property. And if you want deep nested object define them as other schemas and main object should be `{type: 'NAME_OF_OTHER_SCHEMA'}`

Comment: https://github.com/jon49/json-schema-to-mongoose

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking into this. Since you placed a `node` tag on your question, I found these `npm` repos:

- https://github.com/jon49/json-schema-to-mongoose
- https://github.com/topliceanu/mongoose-gen

Both are working so far.

They are both a few years old. The former (TypeScript) has more recent commits. I may end up liking the latter more.